# How to get the URL when I click a button in WebView and Toast the id in android

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a web with the url like this:

**https://sampleweb.com**

I display it on android using WebView. The Website have a button when I click the button the URL change to like this and go to another page:

**https://sampleweb.com?34JGLSDJDJF8**

How to do that when I click the button from WebView the ID(34JGLSDJDJF8) will Toast to android or store the ID to variable.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed this after navigating the page

```
 String url=myWebView.getUrl().toString();

        String[] spli = url.split("/");
        if (spli[spli.length-1]!=null){
            String data = spli[spli.length-1];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Where should i put this? @Somnath

Comment: while you click the the button, ie. button clicklistener

Comment: follow my next answer

Comment: my button is in WebView how to connect them?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```